# insert data in destination table without defining meta data in SSIS package

Tags: sql, ssis

I am creating an SSIS package which gets data dynamically, creates table in destination and inserts data there.

But I don't want to define meta data in script component so that when I select something from different source and different table then it simply insert that data into destination table.
So please suggest which component I should use.
to get every thing dynamically without knowing columns.
Dealing with tables only not with excel or another type.
Here is the snap shot of script component
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this in a dataflow at all.   Dataflows have static meta data that must be defined at design time.

I recommend that you use BiML, which dynamically generates packages based on meta data at run time.

Otherwise you can do the entire thing (Source and Destination) in a single script Task (not dataflow component).

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I find an alternate way to make it done. thanks